# Angular Material - Setting fixed widths?

Tags: css, angularjs, flexbox, material-design

I've been following the Angular Material documentation [here](https://material.angularjs.org/latest/layout/children) but am having trouble with this section:

> flex="none"   Will not grow or shrink. Sized based on its width and
>   height values.

How do I set the width and the height values? I've tried CSS but they are ignored due to "flex" being enabled.

Sorry if this is a stupid question - the documentation just doesn't say how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Angular Material's Layout features provide sugar to enable developers
>   to more easily create modern, responsive layouts on top of CSS3
>   flexbox.

If you want fixed width and height in terms of pixels you can use your tags, say `md-content` without the `flex` property and give it the CSS in the usual way:

**HTML**

```
<md-content>Some content</md-content>
```

**CSS**

```
md-content {
    background-color: teal;
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
}
```

---

**Flex** makes things simpler. You can set the height and width easily using flex properties. For example, this code will set the `div` width to `50%`

```
<div layout="row">
  <div style="background-color:teal; height: 50px;" flex="50">
  </div>
</div>
```

Check out [this](https://material.angularjs.org/1.1.1/layout/introduction) reference to the Angular-material layout documentation.